# How to reset the plugins without deactivate the plugin

Tags: plugins, functions

```
function set_copyright_options() {
    delete_option('ptechsolcopy_notice');
    delete_option('ptechsolcopy_reserved');

    add_option('ptechsolcopy_notice','Copyright &copy;');
    add_option('ptechsolcopy_reserved','All Rights Reserved');

}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'set_copyright_options');
```

Hi I use the code to make it plugin default while deactivate and activate plugin .But i need the options to make it using the reset button in the admin side to make it default without deactivate the plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make another function with will (re)set the default option values:

```
function wpse_91307_set_option_defaults() {
  $options = array(
    'ptechsolcopy_notice'   => 'Copyright &copy;',
    'ptechsolcopy_reserved' => 'All Rights Reserved'
  );

  foreach ( $options as $option => $default_value ) {
    if ( ! get_option( $option ) ) {
        add_option( $option, $default_value );
    } else {
        update_option( $option, $default_value );
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could change your `set_copyright_options()` function into this:

```
function set_copyright_options() {
  delete_option( 'ptechsolcopy_notice' );
  delete_option( 'ptechsolcopy_reserved' );

  wpse_91307_set_option_defaults( );
}
```

When you hit the `reset` button, the only thing you have to do is execute the `wpse_91307_set_option_defaults()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) to create the page. In the callback function, add a form with a reset button:

```
function reset_my_options() {
  add_menu_page( 'Reset Options', 'Reset Options', 'manage_options', 'reset-options', 'reset_option_page' );
}

function reset_option_page() {
if ( isset( $_POST['reset_options'] ) && $_POST['reset_options'] === 'true' ) {

delete_option('ptechsolcopy_notice');
delete_option('ptechsolcopy_reserved');

}
  ?>

  <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Reset options</h2>

    <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=reset-options' ); ?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Click to reset plugin options" style="float:left;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="reset_options" value="true" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

You can also add [nonces](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) to it for further security.

BTW, you could have use [`update_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) in your plugin activation instead of `delete_option` and `add_option`.